# Bootstrap 5: How to implement gradient color on tooltips?

Tags: html, css, sass, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I have faced some issues while I'm trying to gradient color on **bootstrap 5 tooltips**

**CSS:**

```
.tooltip .tooltip-arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

.bs-tooltip-top .tooltip-arrow::before, 
.bs-tooltip-auto[data-popper-placement^=top] .tooltip-arrow::before {
  top: -1px;
  border-width: 0.4rem 0.4rem 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}
```

**Live Example:** https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/NWabvad

Answer (score 1):

By adding a .bg-gradient class, a linear gradient is added as background image to the backgrounds or To use gradient background colors, you need to set $enable-gradients property to true. By default, it is set to false.
Refer link for more understanding
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/colors-and-gradients-in-bootstrap-with-examples/
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/background/